# How maintain data context when have to save object to session variable in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, session-variables, datacontext

I have an ASP.NET page named EditEmployee.aspx.  When loaded (passing EmployeeId in the query string), it populates textboxes and other controls.

An employee is associated to one and only one company office in the U.S.  A dropdownlist hierarchy of

State
   City
     Office

is displayed.

If the user clicks to change the City, I need to do a postback to populate a new list of offices in that city.

While I can save the Employee object to a session variable during Page_Load, it seems as though I lose data context when bringing that object back from session once it's time to save.

How do I remedy this, please?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to do full postback? Is AJAX out of the question?

Comment: It'll still do a postback, though, where I have if (!IsPostBack) in my Page_Load event so it won't go back through all the code that populates the page on initial load.  I suppose I could remove if (!IsPostBack) but that seems wrong to run through all that code on every postback.

Answer (score 1):

You should not save the employee object or the content object in the session variable but rather use the id from the query string to query the data. The data context objects are data providers that are made to be created and disposed as in the case of a unit-of-work approach using using,

Answer (score 0):

I would put the dropdown lists in an [Update Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and re-bind the Office dropdown list when a new selection is made in the City dropdown.

Briefly...

Front-end:  Add a `ScriptManager` to your page and wrap the dropdown lists in an `UpdatePanel`.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" 
                          runat="server" 
                          OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCityChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOffices"
                          runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind, just wire up the event handler like normal.

```
protected void ddlCityChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var city = ddlCity.SelectedValue;
    // get the offices for that city
    ddlOffices.DataSource = [offices];
    ddlOffices.DataBind();
}
```

The UpdatePanel will trigger a partial postback instead of a full postback and use Ajax to only refresh the part of the page that's within the UpdatePanel.  The rest of the page shouldn't be affected.